# List all yarn application in hadoop cluster through java

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

On running command **`yarn application -list`** on my hadoop cluster, it returns list of applications running.

I want to fetch this list using Java.

Currently I am using yarnClient API

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My code looks like :

```
    YarnConfiguration conf = new YarnConfiguration();
    YarnClient yarnClient = YarnClient.createYarnClient();
    yarnClient.init(conf);
    yarnClient.start();
    List<ApplicationReport> list =  yarnClient.getApplications();
    System.out.print(list.size());
    yarnClient.stop();
```

But this gets hanged at line `List<ApplicationReport> list =  yarnClient.getApplications()` and doesn't move forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had my code hang on `#getApplications()` when my YarnConfiguration wasn't properly configured. By default it uses `0.0.0.0:8032` as Yarn Resource Manager address. I had to overwrite this with correct address:

```
YarnConfiguration conf = new YarnConfiguration();
conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "<hostname>:<port>");
YarnClient yarnClient = YarnClient.createYarnClient();
yarnClient.init(conf);
yarnClient.start();
```

I tested this with Hadoop 2.6.0, but looks like defaults are the same for 2.7.0  as well (see [sources](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/d4c8d4d4d203c934e8074b31289a28724c0842cf/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-api/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/conf/YarnConfiguration.java#L131)).

Comment: The application still used to hang at "getApplications()". So, instead of running it as java applicaation (java -jar), i submitted it as a spark application (spark-submit). It worked.