# Get the number of running queries on Spark at the same time

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a cluster with one Spark master and three Spark workers which are used to query on Cassandra. Also I have a UI app with java that the users can insert the query fields on the UI widgets.

Since some users use my system, so I have multiple queries with Spark on Cassandra at the same time.

I know that `SparkListener` can show start of a job or some thing like that, but I don't see any function to get the current running jobs on Spark in `SparkListener`. Just there are some functions that can handle some request like started job or task or ...

Now how can I get the number of queries which are running on my Spark by the users queries for example on every 5 seconds (in java or scala)?

I saw the following questions but my problem does not solve:

[Get current number of running containers in Spark on YARN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825993/get-current-number-of-running-containers-in-spark-on-yarn)

[Spark - How many Executors and Cores are allocated to my spark job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162063/spark-how-many-executors-and-cores-are-allocated-to-my-spark-job/39163142#39163142)

Comment: Spark History Server --https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

Comment: @TahaNaqvi thanks but I see that "Spark History Server Configuration Options" is just some options that can control maxApplications or retainedApplications ... . But how can I see the number of the current queries running on Spark?

Comment: yarn application -list | grep "SPARK" | grep "RUNNING" | wc -l

Comment: @TahaNaqvi thanks, can I access this from java code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717163/list-all-yarn-application-in-hadoop-cluster-through-java...   .refer this and  create objects of response and filter on type of app.